# Parallels Desktop to OS X brower actions

Tags: macos, safari, parallels-desktop, web-browser

I have a customer with a Macbook Air running Windows with Parallels Desktop.
When he clicks on a hyperlink in a Windows application he wants OS X Safari to respond.
Is this possible somehow?

To make things even more complicated some of the pages he wants to open are not online but local files inside the Windows enviroment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into your Virtual Machine Configuration, on the left menu select "Internet Applications" and the right toggle "Web Pages" to say "Open in Mac OS X".

[image]